# SQL substring with charIndex

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to select a part of a string in two query

1. **"Server \ Windows  \ Access Database"**
2. **"Access Database \ Server \ Windows"**

i want to select whatever is there after the first **'\'**   in one query
and in second query i want to select the text after second **'\'**

between the **'\'** the length of the text keeps changing.

I have tried:

```
SELECT Somecolumn=Substring(column1, 0, Charindex('\', column1, 1)) 
FROM   dbo.sometable
```

The result:

```
SOMECOLUMN
Server
Access Database
```

Sql-Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0458/1

Comment: @Tim am using this query select Somecolumn=substring(column1,0,charindex('\',column1,1)) from table in on query i want "Access Databae" as a result and in another i want "Windows"

Comment: So what is your desired result? Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by two queries? and your expected results are completely different to the description.

Comment: my actual query is select CaseType = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Description,0,CHARINDEX('\',Description,1)))) from mytable by runnig this am getting 'server' as the output in short befoe first '\'. i want the output by using two diffrent query in first i want the output after first '\' and in second i want the ouput after second '\'

Answer (score 2):

To get the string after first "\" you can use the below query:

```
declare @residence varchar(200)
set @residence='Server \ Windows \ Access Database'
select left(@residence, CHARINDEX('\',@residence)-1) AS [Result]
```

and for second : you want to get the string after second "\": for this you can use below query

```
select RIGHT(@residence, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE('\' + @residence)) - 1) AS [Result]
```

thats all

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create table t (val varchar(50))

insert into t
select 'Server \ Windows \ Access Database'
union all
select 'Access Database \ Server \ Windows'
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/deee3/7)**:

```
;with cte as (

  select charindex('\',val,0) index1,
              charindex('\',val, charindex('\',val,0)+1) index2
  from t        
)
select val, right(val, len(val) - index1) first,
            right(val, len(val) - index2) second
from cte

|                      FIRST |           SECOND |
-----------------------------|------------------|--
|  Windows \ Access Database |  Access Database |
|           Server \ Windows |          Windows |
```